# Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties when use google-cloud-speech

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-speech

> I have a error when i use **google-cloud-speech** in my app. I couldn't
>   find any solution regarding this.

**`Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties when use google-cloud-speech`**

**Error Log:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied 
in APK project.properties
File1: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-speech\0.17.1-
alpha\465fbf7a46b1b1fc3ecc8bb0371bdde7148242fd\google-cloud-speech-0.17.1-
alpha.jar
File2: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-
core\1.0.0\a204545d321c4f1688d9c377cdd88310884842f4\google-cloud-core-
1.0.0.jar
```

I tried below two ways, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem!!

Thank you in advance !

**one:**

```
    compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.17.1-alpha'){
    exclude group: 'org.json'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-all'
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-
 appengine'
    }
```

**two:**

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please add *exclude 'project.properties'* in packagingOptions.